# Calculate the norm of a 3D array using pagefun - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpu

Is it possible to use `pagefun` to calculate the norm (and execute other built-in GPU functions - http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/run-built-in-functions-on-a-gpu.html) on multiple pages simultaneously?

For example, I need to calculate the norms of a 3D array.

```
N = 10000
Sig = gpuArray(2,2000,N) % This is just to get an idea of the dimensions. Its populated elsewhere

% This is what I am currently doing.
for k = 1:N
    TNorm(k,:) = [norm(Sig(1,:,k),2) norm(Sig(2,:,k),2)];
end
```

Is there a way to execute it in one go rather than iterate through the 3rd dimension to calculate the norm each time? Can something like this be done?

```
pagefun(norm(Sig,2)) % This gives the error: Input data must be a double or single vector or 2D matrix.
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a 3D array, in your case lets call it E:

E = rand(3,3,4) % This is a 3D array with size 3x3x4

if you want to calculate the norm of page so from 1 to 4 in this case, you can use:

```
norm_E = arrayfun(@(idx) norm(E(:,:,idx)), 1:size(E,3))
```

The output will be:

```
norm_E = [(norm array 1),(norm array 2),(norm array 3),(norm array 4)]
```

You are also not limited to the 2-norm you can use any norm you please for example if you wanted to use the infinity norm you could put:

```
norm_E = arrayfun(@(idx) norm(E(:,:,idx),inf), 1:size(E,3))
```

Using arrayfun is faster than a for loop. I apologize if you are restricted to using pagefun I do not have that feature with my version of Matlab.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I implemented arrayfun but according to MATLAB profiler, the for-loop manages to do it faster somehow.. Worth mentioning that the array `E` you have defined is a gpuArray in my case, and I am executing arrayfun on a GPU.